# Client doesnt load assets after adding last-modified header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, thin, last-modified

Im running my rails app in production mode using thin and nginx (0.7.6) on Debian. Its working pretty well but not I tried to implement the last-modified header and when I restart nginx the client doesnt load the assets anymore.

This is my nginx config:

```
upstream instance-name {
        server unix:/var/run/thin/appname.0.sock;
        server unix:/var/run/thin/appname.1.sock;
        server unix:/var/run/thin/appname.2.sock;
        server unix:/var/run/thin/appname.3.sock;
}

server {
        listen 5678;
        server_name appname;
        access_log /root/rails/appname/log/access.log;
        error_log /root/rails/appname/log/error.log;
        root /root/rails/appname/public;
        index index.html;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;

                if (-f $request_filename/index.html) {
                        rewrite (.*) $1/index.html break;
                }

                if (-f $request_filename.html) {
                        rewrite (.*) $1.html break;
                }

                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                        proxy_pass http://fibre-dox;
                        break;
                }
        }
        location ~* \.(jpg|gif|png|css|js)$ {
               if (-f $request_filename) {
                       expires max;
                       break;
               }
        }
}
```

The part that causes me trouble is this one:

```
location ~* \.(jpg|gif|png|css|js)$ {
                   if (-f $request_filename) {
                           expires max;
                           break;
                   }
            }
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to use the last-modified header so the client doesnt reload all the pics everytime it hits the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html @backend;

            location ~* \.(?:jpg|gif|png|css|js)$ {
                try_files $uri @backend;
                expires max;
            }
    }

    location @backend {
            proxy_pass http://fibre-dox;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;

            location ~* \.(?:jpg|gif|png|css|js)$ {
                proxy_pass http://fibre-dox;
                expires max;
            }
    }
```

- http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil
- http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html
- http://nginx.org/r/try_files
- http://nginx.org/r/location

Comment: this also doesnt do it for me. Im using version 0.7.6 that might be a problem?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe. This is a very ancient version. And, by the way, it has security problems. Regardless of your problem you should update your nginx.